# Problema ao editar uma lista em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não to entendendo o que ta acontecendo com esse trecho de codigo. O esperado era que quando *printasse* a lista no final ele os elementos dela *splitados*, mas está retornando a lista como se nada tivesse acontecido.
(Cada elemento da lista inicial é uma frase. quando dou .split() quero que ele transforme cada um desses elementos em uma nova lista onde as palavras estão separadas)

```
x = open ('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines()

for l in lista:
    l = l.split()

print(lista)
```

Comment: A lista não é alterada em momento nenhum, para todos os efeitos é como se o seu `for` não existisse. Pois o que você quer ver é a variável `l` mas printa a `lista`. Você pode botar um `print(l)` dentro do `for` para ver o resultado do `str.split()`

Answer (score 4):

Fazer

```
for l in lista:
    l = l.split()
```

É similar a fazer:

```
for i in range (0,len(lista)):
    l = lista[i]
    l = l.split()
```

Que é igual a:

```
for i in range (0,len(lista)):
    l = lista[i].split()
```

Note que apenas o valor da variável `l` foi alterado, mas não o valor de `lista[i]`. Por isso que `lista` não é alterada.

Uma solução para este problema, seguindo a sugestão do comentário do Bruno, é usar lista por compreensão:

```
x = open ('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines()

lista = [l.split() for l in lista]

print(lista)
```

Comment: +1. Para a resposta ficar mais completa, podia incluir um exemplo, mostrando como obter o resultado que o Juliano pretende. Por exemplo, usando enumerate ou lista por compreensão [l.split() for l in lista]

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.
O que esta havendo no seu código é um erro de indentação.

O Correto seria:

```
x = open ('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines()

for l in lista:    # Para cada l na lista
    l = l.split()  # l recebera um .split()
    print(l)       # E mostrará cada l
```

Assim, para cada elemento dentro da lista, o laço `for` vai imprimir a *linha*.

O `l.split()` existe apenas dentro do laço `for`, devido a regra de indentação do Python.

Caso voce queira adicionar os valor com `split()` a outra lista, voce pode usar uma lambada, ou pode por exemplo, criar uma lista vazia acima e entao adicionar os valores novos a ela:

```
 x = open ('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines()

nova_lista = []
for l in lista:    # Para cada l na lista
    l = l.split()  # l recebera um .split()
    nova_lista.append(l) # Adiciona o valor para a nova lista   
print(nova_lista)
```

Comment: Lembrando apenas, que o `.split()` sem atribuição interna, vai separar cada valor dentro do `l` nos _espaços_.

Comment: Como trocar `lista` por `l` é um erro de indentação?

Comment: Nao foi isso que eu disse, para tanto coloquei o código ali. O `l.split()` só existe dentro do laço `for`.
Se ele precisar criar outra lista com os elementos 'splitados', poderia uma lambda ou então criar a lista vazia antes. E sim, à o erro de indentação, pois o `print(l)` deve ficar dentro do `for`.

Comment: Mas não existe `print(l)` no código dele, foi isso que eu quis dizer...

Comment: @Anderson muito grato. Mas ainda nao entendi por que a lista não é alterada quando eu altero um ''l''. Eu achava que quando fizesse um "l = l.split" aquela linha da lista seria alterada e ,portanto, quando eu imprimisse a lista ela apareceria em sua nova forma.

Comment: No lugar de `nova.append(l)`, o correto é `nova_lista.append(l)`.

Comment: Isso acontece porque com o TAB voce altera a camada de indentação a qual o código esta executando.
na linha abaixo do `for` voce colocou um tab, e entao o `l = l.split()`
Isso significa na pratica, de que esse `l` com split só existe "dentro do `for`

Comment: Podemos dizer, que o `l` esta 'Encapsulado' dento do `for`.

Comment: Para complementar sobre a indentação. O Python, assim como a maioria das linguagens, executa o Código de Cima para baixo, e da esquerda para a direita. O mais simples pra voce entender a indentação, seria virar o monitor de lado, o `l = l.split()` estaria dentro do laço `for`

Answer (score 0):

Opa,

Você tem que atualizar o valor da lista no laço *for*

```
x = open ('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines() # a lista está parada aqui

for l in lista: # aqui está sendo apenas passado os valores da lista para um variavel.
    l = l.split() # aqui está sendo apenas atualizado o valor na própria variável do laço

print(lista) # printando a lista do mesmo jeito que foi declarada
```

Você tem que interagir com o *for* dentro do próprio laço.

```
x = open('exemplo1.txt','r')
lista = x.readlines()

# aqui pode usar o enumerate pra pegar o index da lista e valor
for i, l in enumerate(lista):
   # ao mesmo tempo que dividi a lista com split, você altera o valor na mesma posição.
   lista[i] = lista[i].split()

print(lista)
```

A saída nesse caso vai ser uma lista com todos os valores da lista que foi percorrida pelo laço.

```
[ ['exemplo', exemplo2'], ['exemplo3', 'exemplo4'], ... ]
```